# How to specify an array input parameter as const

Tags: typescript

I want to send an *immutable array* to a class constructor:

```js
class Student {
  constructor(private readonly grades: Array<number>){}
  getMaxGrade(){ return Math.max(...this.grades); }
}

const lastYearGrades = [94, 86, 90] as const;

const s = new Student(lastYearGrades);
```

- The data member `grades` *is not allowed* to change
- The *content* of `grades` is also not allowed to change

Here is the error I get:

```
$ npx tsc main.ts
main.ts:8:23 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'readonly [94, 86, 90]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
  The type 'readonly [94, 86, 90]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'number[]'.

8 const s = new Student(lastYearGrades);
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: The _property_ being readonly is different to the _value_ being readonly. How to solve this depends on the actual _behaviour_ you want - maybe `(private grades: readonly number[])`, maybe a type assertion, maybe something else.

Comment: I want it to be frozen - both the values of the array and the data member itself

Comment: Well right now you're saying the value is _not_ `readonly`, it needs to be a _mutable_ array. The compiler is correctly telling you `lastYearGrades` doesn't meet that requirement. That the property to which it's assigned is then readonly is, again, not the same thing - that just means a whole new array value can't be assigned to it inside the class.

Comment: I don't see what's surprising. `this.grades = [123]` and `this.grades.push(456)` mutate entirely different objects. The readonliness of the property and the value are separate; either, both or neither can be readonly depending on what behaviour you want.

Comment: @jonrsharpe no, I want that the data member can NOT be changed - neither by replacing it, nor by changing its values -

Comment: You have two things you want to be readonly. You've said _only one of them_ should be. If you want them both to be, _say that_: https://tsplay.dev/we8aBW

Comment: Yes, I see but when I try your suggestion with `:readonly Array<number>` instead of `: readonly number[]` it doesn't work - that's weird because I thought the 2 were the same

Comment: As it tells you _"'readonly' type modifier is only permitted on array and tuple literal types. (1354)"_ - if you want to use the generic form of array _use the generic form of readonly_, `Readonly<Array<number>>`.